# How to code ranges to fixed value in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How to code more ranges to fixed value? I’d like to set several intervals of a period for fixed value in python.

```
import numpy as np
U=np.zeros(50)
U[2:15]=100
```

How to set more intervals ［20:30], [40:45] in U within 50?

Comment: In the same way as the 2:15 part? It's unclear what you otherwise want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution using *chain from itertools could be:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

U=np.zeros(50)
U[list(chain.from_iterable([list(range(2,15)), list(range(25,30))]))] = 100
```

This assumes that the indices you're interested in all are from certain ranges as you have indicated in your question.

To make this more easy to read, you could write a small function to convert your ranges into a list of indices with which you can subset U:

```
def list_index(interval_list):
  
  full_list = []
  for i in interval_list:
    full_list_i = list(range(i[0],i[1]))
    full_list.append(full_list_i)
  indices = list(chain.from_iterable(full_list))
  return indices
```

and then use this directly in your list:

```
U=np.zeros(50)
U[list_index([[2,10],[15,20]])] = 100
```

I am sure this could be coded a bit more elegant and faster, but it should work as a first solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly:

You can pass a list to get acces the values. If you want to acces multiple ranges you just have to create a list composed of multiple ranges. The easiest way to do it is this one:

```py
import numpy as np
U=np.zeros(50)
U[[*range(2,15), *range(20,30), *range(40,45)]]=100
```

The * operator is used to concatenate any number of lists and just works on Python 3.6+.

Another option is just to write it in multiple lines:

```py
import numpy as np
U=np.zeros(50)
U[2:15]=100
U[20:30]=100
U[40:45]=100
```

Comment: You answer my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use multiple assignments

```
import numpy as np
U = np.zeros(50)
U[2:15], U[20:30], U[40:45] = 100, 100, 100
```

Comment: Another doable solution. Thanks